# Interchange all occurrences of a character and its predecessor

Tags: php, strings, unicode

Given a string like `"abcdbcfbc"` , I want all the occurrences of 'b' to be interchanged with their previous character.
The output should be: `"bacbdcbfc"`

I've come up with a temporary solution:

```
function punjabi_alternate($string) {
    $len = mb_strlen($string);
    $sploded = array(); 
    while($len-- > 0) {
        $sploded[$len] = mb_substr($string, $len, 1); 
    }
    ksort($sploded);
    $len = mb_strlen($string);
    for ($i=0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        if( strcmp($sploded[$i], "b") == 0){
            $temp = $sploded[$i];
            $sploded[$i] = $sploded[$i-1];
            $sploded[$i-1] = $temp;
        }
    } 
    return join('', $sploded);
}
```

Here I'm using `mb_substr` as my string contains unicode characters. The **b** is just an example.
In my production version I'm using this instead of **"b"**

```
html_entity_decode("&#x0A3F;")
```

It is working as expected.
I'd appreciate if there could be a cleaner way to do it.
Also the strings passed to the function can contain as many as 10,000 - 20,000 characters.
So, I'd prefer a `preg_replace` function with regex to do the same.

Comment: [Related Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43193096/1157100). It looks like you are asking for a regex-based solution rather than a review of the existing code, so I don't believe that Code Review is the appropriate place to ask this question.

Comment: regex based solution was a secondary requirement. I just wanted to optimize the code for usage with large strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do a string replacement operation, so use `preg_replace()`.  The key is to use backreferences in the `replacement`.  Also, since you seem to be interested in processing Unicode, be sure to use the [`u` flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for the regex.

If, as you say, `'b'` is just an example, then you can make it a default parameter.

```
function punjabi_alternate($string, $char='b') {
    return preg_replace("/(.)($char)/u", '\2\1', $string);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. before i was trying the similar expression with . (Dot) and $char in single parenthesis . It was giving me single string containing both elements. It never occured to me to use both characters with different parentheses.